# Authors of "How to explain zero-knowledge Protocols to your children?"

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, reference-request, history

Does anyone know what are the family relationships in the paper ["How to Explain Zero-Knowledge Protocols to Your Children"](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Emkowalcz/628.pdf)

The authors are: Jean-Jacques Quisquater, Myriam Quisquater, Muriel Quisquater, Michaël Quisquater, Louis C. Guillou, Marie Annick Guillou, Gaïd Guillou, Anna Guillou, Gwenolé Guillou, Soazig Guillou, Thomas A. Berson

I suppose its Jean-Jacques Quisquaterm, Louis C. Guillou and their children but I cannot find any source to verify this.

I want to add it as a "joke" in a presentation I have about SNARKs.